# The amount of VS The number of, etc

Tags: quantifiers

Is it OK to use **the amount of** with countable nouns? I have come across the usage of it with **people**, but I am confused whether to use it with countables.

What about **the proportion of**? How different is it from **the amount of** and **the number of** ?

Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: I would favour *amount* for uncountable things like volume or mass, but colloquially it can be used for people.

Comment: Can you add some example sentences?  It's hard to say without context.

Comment: For instance, The number of people commuting by bus considerably increased in the year of 2013. I mean what if I say The amount of people OR the proportion of people? @MaxWilliams

Comment: It appears that this question arises from a comment I made in [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337648/ielts-exam-writing-task-1-introduction). OP wrote: "The pie charts compare the amount of people enrolled on six courses, ...". I commented: " we would not normally say "*amount* of people" - either *number* of people (if you are showing actual numbers) or *proportion* of people (if using, say, percentages). amount is used for 'non-discrete' items" ..."

Comment: @TurkanAlisoy both are fine but mean different things.  "number" and "amount" are synonymous in this context, but "number" feels more correct to me.  Number and amount are the total number, eg "6 million people".  Proportion is the **relative** amount, compared to the larger group of people, commuting **and** non-commuting, and would normally be expressed as a percentage, eg *"The proportion of people commuting by bus considerably increased in 2013, from 15% to 25%."*

Comment: @TrevorD I agree but can you expand a little on what you mean by "non-discrete items"?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Please use the link in my comment to the previous Q. - My comment is the first one under the Q.

Comment: @TrevorD i see.  I was going to write something about measurement being the key but couldn't quite put it into words for some reason.  Thanks.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I think I got the point about proportion, excellent example, thank you. But still a bit confused about the others.

Answer (score 2):

This question appears to arise from a comment I made in an [earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337648/ielts-exam-writing-task-1-introduction).

Op had written:

> The pie charts compare the amount of people enrolled on six courses, … in a certain college in the UK.

I had commented:

> We would not normally say "*amount* of people" - either *number* of people (if you are showing actual numbers) or *proportion* of people (if using, say, percentages). *amount* is used for 'non-discrete' items (i.e. things that you *cannot count*, but can only *measure* e.g. by weight or volume, such as sugar or a liquid.

OP is now asking about the usage of *amount* is a sentence such as:

> The number of people commuting by bus considerably increased in the year of 2013.

and asks whether *amount* or *proportion* could replace *number*.

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amount) defines **amount** as follows and includes a Grammar Note:

> **amount**
>   noun [countable]
>   a collection or mass, especially of something that cannot be counted:
>   [example sentences omitted - see [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amount)]
>
> Grammar
>   ***Amount of or number of?***
>   We use *amount of* with uncountable nouns. *Number of* is used with countable nouns:
>
> - *We use a huge **amount of paper** in the office every day.*
> - *The **amount of time** it took to finish the job was very frustrating.*
> - *A great **number of students** volunteer each year for environmental projects.*
> - **Not:** *A great amount of students volunteer …*
> - *I have **a number of things** I want to talk to you about.*

The original sentence refers to "[comparing] the amount of people enrolled on six courses [using a pie chart]".  The context clearly suggests that the actual *numbers* of student involved are known.  In that instance, it seems that *number* or *proportion* (depending on the values actually shown in the pie chart) would be appropriate; and that *amount* would, at best, be non-idiomatic.  That view is reinforces by the *Grammar Note* above indicating that "*A great **amount** of students volunteer …*" would be wrong.

In the second example sentence:

- *amount* may be more acceptable because there is (presumably) no reference to precise numbers;
- even so, *number* still sounds more idiomatic to me; and would refer to the *overall* (estimated) number of bus commuters using buses;
- *proportion* would be appropriate only if there were a comparison with (for example) the overall number of commuters.

**But beware:** in this case the difference between *number* and *proportion* could be important, because one value could go up while the other value goes down.  For example:
 - Year 1: 4 million commuters use the bus; 6 million use the train; hence 40% (of the total 10 million) use the bus.
 - Year 5: 5 million commuters use the bus; 8 million use the train; hence 38.5% (of the total 13 million) use the bus.
Thus the *number* of bus commuters has *increased* by 1 million (23%), but the *proportion* of bus commuters has *decreased* by 1.5%.

Comment: Isn't part of the problem the use of the word 'countable'?  When I was at university two generations ago, the term used in the philosophy faculty was 'count'.  One talked about 'count nouns' and 'mass nouns'.  This did not mean that a 'mass noun' was somehow 'non-countable'.  Words like 'people', or 'cheese' or 'steel' are often (perhaps mostly) used to refer to a mass and so in the singular, referring to stuff that we measure rather than count.  It does not means that it is 'uncountable'.  there are many cheeses but when buying it, we buy it by (non-count) mass/weight, not number.

Answer (score 1):

**The proportion** would refer to the percentage with reference to a larger total.

If you refer to the **amount of people** without quantifying them exactly, this would be okay as a group of "people" may be undefined and uncounted. However if you counted them, then **the number of people** sounds better.

The proportion of people who responded to the letter.
The amount of people using the facilities.
The number of people/persons on the train exceeded the safe limit of 500.

Comment: Can you expand a little on the subtle difference between "number of people" and "amount of people", with reference to the "facilities" example?  It's an interesting distinction.

Comment: We talk of "*large* amounts" & "*high* numbers" - not normally of "*high* amounts".

Comment: @TrevorD I corrected my mistake. So according to samdawe's post, 'The amount of people commuting by bus was large.' is OK?

Comment: I can't readily explain it, but "the amount was large" is not idiomatic. We just would not say "The amount of people commuting by bus was large." "A large amount of people commuted by bus" *might* be a little better, but still sounds non-idiomatic to me. See the second quoted paragraph in Edwin Ashworth's answer. Also see my full Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

[Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/amount-number/) has a balanced article dealing with the subtle 'tacit massification' of count nouns that occurs in situations like this.

> **Amount vs. number**
>
> *Amount* is used in reference to mass nouns (i.e., uncountable nouns such as bravery, water, and charisma). *Number* is used in reference
>   to count nouns (i.e., countable nouns such as dog, year, and eyeball).
>
> For example, because the noun **person** can be counted, the phrase
>   **amount of people** might be considered incorrect. The distinction tends to weaken, however, when we’re talking about great numbers. *The
>   amount of people in the room* would sound wrong to many careful
>   speakers of English, while *the amount of people in China* would not
>   seem so glaringly wrong (though many English-speakers would still
>   consider it questionable). In any case, it’s always safer to use
>   number in situations like this.

It's really a metaphorical usage, considering countable elements as an amorphous whole. 'The volume of people' is a slightly different metaphorical usage, but is quite a common usage.

...

*Proportion* is used with both count- and non-count situations (the proportion of left-handed pupils in the class; the proportion of ethanol in the sample).